# Approximation of infimum

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose $f$ is a continuous function over a subset $U$ of a finite dimensional set $V$. When can I say that "We can find a sequence $x_n\in U$ such that $f(x_n)\to \inf_{x\in U} f(x)$"?

Does $U$ have to be open?

Comment: If $f$ is real-valued, you can always find such a sequence, by the definition of an infimum. No constraints on $U$.

Comment: How about $f$ is not continuous?

Comment: What is a finite-dimensional set? I know what a finite-dimensional vector space is, and I know there are a couple sorts of "topological dimension" (whatever that is) and then there's fractal dimension, whatever that is, but I don't know what sort of dimension you mean.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Let $m = \inf_{x\in U} f(x)$. Well, there's one constraint, $U$ mustn't be empty. Then, by definition of $\inf$, for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, there is some $x_n\in U$ with $f(x_n) < m + \frac{1}{n+1}$. Otherwise, $m$ would not be the _greatest_ lower bound.

Comment: @DanielFischer, I'm sorry. I have a bit of a tendency to act like an old-fashioned compiler sometimes, declaring "parse error" or "type error" or "unbound variable" and making no effort to make sense of whatever follows.

Comment: @dfeuer Well, I for one am happy that compilers nowadays give better error messages than "Syntax error on line xyz, possibly missing ';' on line above" ;-)

Comment: @DanielFischer, if you want some *interesting times*, try learning to interpret type checker error messages in Glasgow Haskell with the most popular extensions enabled.

Comment: @dfeuer What are the most popular extensions? BangPatterns, MagicHash, UnboxedTuples, CPP don't make funny type error messages, and those are the most popular with me.

Comment: @DanielFischer, I was thinking more about existential types and such. (I know *just enough* to get myself in trouble.)

Comment: @dfeuer ExistentialQuantification is _relatively_ harmless. There are all sorts of really weird new things that can produce much less penetrable messages. Good thing I stay away from them.